How to implement OOP design which includes data classes that might change later?
I am working on a simple CLI todo list manager application in Java to test my skills. I've read a few things about OOP design patterns and principles. Like you should not have much dependencies between objects, singular responsibility principle etc. But my questions is that, what about data classes? Like if I am creating a todo list app, I will need a Task class for storing tasks. Lets say first version of Task have, title, dueDate, and isDone fields. I build my system to work with this data class. But in second version, lets say I add another field called priority. So there will be changed in my system. This is a very basic example. But I'm sure that this kind of changes also happens in real world applications. So does this means that we have to change any logic that is working with the Task class, or there are practices to save from this situations?
I read some articles online about OOP design practices and SOLID principles. But they mostly talk about the operations and interaction of objects with each other. I could not find anything suitable for data classes specifically. I would appreciate if anyone can share any experience regarding such matter. The example I have provided here is very basic, but I hope the you get idea of what I want to say. I'm a beginner and don't have any real words experience so I could not provide any better example. Thank you for your time!

You can add your priority field to your data class along with a getter and setter, that is not a problem per se. If you need to apply changes in the logic because of this new field, then you will need to implement this yourself.
The question you need to ask yourself is this:
Will priority be an attribute of all the instances of this class?
If the answer it "yes", then you just need to add the field to the class and implement whatever logical changes you need.
If the answer is "no", then you will need to leave your class intact and create a new class which extends this class and override whichever method needs to be changed inside the subclass.
So, if you instantiate the subclass, you will have priority and the logic based on it in place. And, if you instantiate the base class, then it will be left intact.
So, always, you will need to think on whether the change you are to implement will be needed for all instances, or will there be instances that need to work without it.

So if new logic is required when new fields are added, then we just have to implement it. And to ensure things don't stop working, we need to make sure, the logic for different things are not tangled together. The things will only break if we delete existing data, not if we add new.

Just worth noting if you add new fields in an existing class you will increase the memory footprint of that class. Most of the times it doesn't matter but in some cases (e.g. when there's manual memory management involved) it might be worth considering. There may be backwards incompatibilities with code that e.g. relied each Task instance taking X bytes exactly.

@albert_guy yes, exactly.
